# Django pre_save or post_svae is not triggered on through model but post_delete is

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, django-orm

So I am working on a google calendar integration. I have users and shifts and in the through model I want to add a google_calendar_id. So right now I have a through model

```
class ShiftUser(models.Model):
    shift = models.ForeignKey("shift.Shift", models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="shift_users")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="user_shifts")
    google_calendar_id = models.CharField(max_length=1024, null=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("shift", "user"),)
```

But the save method does not work on through model so I added a `pre_save` on the model:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=ShiftUser)
def shift_user_change(instance, **kwargs):
    GoogleIntegration.create_event(instance)
```

I tried this approach with `pre_save` and `post_save` but both are not triggered. But when I use `post_delete` it does work. Does anybody know why this is?

For the record. I tried `m2m_changed` but I need to know which users changed and from what I gathered I can't do that without doing two queries per change in the relationship. This is of course not the worst but I think the pre_save is a cleaner solution.

Comment: how did you create the model instance?

Comment: Using Django rest framework. So just by passing a list of id's of users to the backend when editing a shift. But this is not the only way users are added to shifts. For example when we generate a schedule there are users added by just calling `shift.users.add(users)`